# Como evitar captura automática con php?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$im = imagegrabscreen();
imagepng($im, "mi_captura_de_pantalla.png");
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Hola disculpen como podría evitar que se capture automáticamente esta función en php,que funcione desde un botón o un link

Comment: ?php
$im = imageg
rabscreen();
imagepng
($im, "mi_
captura_de_
pantalla.png
");
imagedestroy
($im);
?>

mi codigo es este ,perdon

Comment: podrías explicar un poco más en escenario en el que quieres usarla.

Comment: Bueno me gustaría implementar esta funcion en un botón en html5 y con css ok y ke cuando el usuario de click en el botón se ejecute el codigo pero ejecuta automáticamente,me explique bien?

Comment: Dejame ver si entendí, quieres crear una página que muestre un botón, cuando la persona presione el botón quieres que se ejecute tu código. pero tu estas colocando el código de la función en un solo archivo, junto con el html de que muestra el botón? o como lo haz intentado hacer?

Comment: Junto al html ?

Answer (score 1):

claro, es porque cada vez que se  carga la pagina, se ejecuta el codigo directamente. 
Para evitar eso deberías meterlo dentro de un IF que detecte un valor de GET o POST, o bien llamarlo dentro de una funcion.

por ejemplo, usando GET:

```
<?php
if($_GET['capturar'] == 'si') {

    $im = imagegrabscreen();
    imagepng($im, "mi_captura_de_pantalla.png");
    imagedestroy($im);

}
?>

<a href="nombre-del-script.php?capturar=si">Capturar Pantalla</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, voy a asumir es que tienes tu servidor configurado correctamente y en windows, siendo que `imagegrabscreen()` solo funciona alli

No se en que archivo tengas actualmente tu código pero para que mi solución funcione debes ponerlo en uno llamado `sacar-foto.php` en el root de tu proyecto

Si quieres que al clickearse un botón en una página puedas ejecutarlo, puede hacerse fácilmente con un `<form>`. El código de la página también debe ir en el root del proyecto y quedaría asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form action="sacar-foto.php">
      <input type="submit" value="SACAR FOTO">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No me funciono :( y cree ke era el php pero probe imprimir un echo y si funciona,ke sucede ??

Comment: Parece que hay que configurar el Apache para que pueda tener interacción con el escritorio según dice [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919550/capture-image-with-imagegrabscreen-and-wamp)